# Apply and receive OPT while on TN?

Tags: usa, working-visas, immigration

I am just now filing for my OPT post completion authorization and realized that the processing times will be such that I could be OPT-less by the time I start work. The TN visa is also an option for me so in the worst case, I would just apply for the TN at the border.

However I was wondering if it was possible to do a change of status from TN to OPT after my OPT gets approved/arrives. Also, will the government deny me of my OPT if I am already on TN? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OPT is part of F1 status, and post-completion OPT must be done right after graduating. If you go into another status after you have graduated, you cannot go back into F1 status to do OPT.